Which word is right to describe a line section which is a side of the rectangle?
I want to specify only one side of a rectangle. I found two participants; border and boundary. But I think boundary is used for whole lines which separates inside and outside of rectangle.
So, my question is, which word is right to describe the red line in the image. Is it 'top border', or 'top boundary'?

Editted on here.
It seems I need to add a condition. The rectangle is on a kind of blueprint.

Either option is clear enough, but I'd prefer "top edge" to both. I think "edge" is the most common term  for this in mathematics.

It's a long, long time since I studied geometry, but I think side is used for the edges of a polygon - so 'the upper side of the rectangle'.

@KateBunting - Oh God! Mr Jamison, 1965, congruent triangles, one of the proofs of congruency was that they matched side, angle, side. Written 'SAS' I recall. I am fairly sure that I have not thought about that for nearly 60 years.

Good point, @Michael Harvey, on this 'SAS'  rule!

A rectangle is a polygon with four sides (a quadrilateral), with four 90-degree vertices. Each side is a line segment.
From Wikipedia: The segments of a closed polygonal chain are called its edges or sides. The points where two edges meet are the polygon's vertices or corners. An n-gon is a polygon with n sides; for example, a triangle is a 3-gon.

We can call it the top (or 'upper') side of the rectangle.  Side is commonly use for this purpose.

If the choice is between border and boundary, "top border" is the correct answer. I see the same in MS word:

The rectangles orientation may differ. Sometimes the short edge may be the top edge.
So the alternative ways of expressing are:
"top long edge" or "top long side".

In a mathematical or other technical context, it would be the top edge, though the top side may be a bit more common in everyday conversation.
